# Media queries viewport issue in IE8

Tags: media-queries

I am having problem using media queries for IE8. Suppose I want specific CSS at 1280px resolution, it is working fine of all browsers except IE8.

The CSS applies on IE8 when I increase the resolution from 1280px to 1301px. I think it is taking scrollbars width too.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are not supported in any version of IE below 9. Use Respond.js. Read the docs for Respond.js

Comment: Thanx for your reply but i think you did not get my question. Its working fine on IE8 but when i add 20px more to the mediaqueries tag i.e. 1301px to support 1280px resolution.